# Without jQuery tell information from external css file or internal stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use javascript **without jQuery or any other JS library** to return styles from internal/external styleshet

```
<style type="text/css"> <!-- From internal/external stylesheet -->
    div{
        height:30px;
        width:45px;
        background-color:#4445C7;
    }
</style>
<div id="counter-element" style="width:3px;height:10px;"></div>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStyle(elem,prop){
        return elem.style[prop];
    }
    alert(getStyle(document.getElementById("counter-element"),"origional-background-color"); //I know this won't work. I'm just putting it in for an example
    alert(getStyle(document.getElementById("example"),"background-color");
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to know what styles apply to a given object from either directly applied styles or stylesheet styles, then you can use `getComputedStyle()` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) in MDN.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this `var es=getStyle(document.getElementById("someId"),"background-color");`

```js
function getStyle(Elm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(Elm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(Elm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = Elm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}
```